# Ошибка при создании inline кнопок

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Выкидывает ошибку(в связи с малым опытом) не могу понять почему

```
if message.text == 'Графики':
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    kalculator = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('Линейная')
    poisk = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('Квадратическая')
    admin = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('Степенная')
    podderzchka = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('обратно-пропорциональная')
    spisoksokr = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('Логарифмическая')
    bistriypoisk = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('Функция в модуле')
    spisoksokr1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('Другие функции(sin,cos)')
    bistriypoisk1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('Вернуться назад⬅️')
    mess = f'Ты в поиске графиков,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери какой график тебе нужен:' 
    markup.add(poisk, admin, podderzchka, spisoksokr, bistriypoisk, kalculator, spisoksokr1, bistriypoisk1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hello' ,reply_markup=markup)
```

(что показывает терминал)

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала рекомендую посмотреть как нужно делать инлайн кнопки и как их обрабатывать. Вы же пытались в `InlineKeyboardMarkup` впихнуть другой `InlineKeyboardMarkup`, а не `InlineKeyboardButton`. Также каждая кнопка должна иметь возвращаемое `callback_data`, и вот это `callback_data` нужно отлавливать в `callback_query_handler()`.

```
if message.text == 'Графики':
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    kalculator = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Линейная', callback_data="linear")
    poisk = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Квадратическая', callback_data="search")
    admin = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Степенная', callback_data="admin")
    podderzchka = types.InlineKeyboardButton('обратно-пропорциональная', callback_data="reverse")
    spisoksokr = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Логарифмическая', callback_data="log")
    bistriypoisk = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Функция в модуле', callback_data="in_module")
    spisoksokr1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Другие функции(sin,cos)', callback_data="other_func")
    bistriypoisk1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Вернуться назад⬅️', callback_data="back")
    mess = f'Ты в поиске графиков,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери какой график тебе нужен:'
    markup.add(poisk, admin, podderzchka, spisoksokr, bistriypoisk, kalculator, spisoksokr1, bistriypoisk1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hello', reply_markup=markup)
```